# Using JARs from Maven in Jersey

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey

I set up a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with Jersey 2 and converted this project to a Maven one. Everythings fine, the application works.

Next I added some dependencies to Mavens pom.xml, and used them in my classes. Eclipse lets me import them. But when I start the application again, Jersey complains about ClassNotFound.

I guess Jersey is not able to find the libaries received by Maven, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Right click on the project and go to Properties. Select Deployment Assembly. Do you see the Maven dependencies in there?

Comment: Woop woop! After I added the Maven Dependencies it worked. Big fckin Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and go to Properties. Select Deployment Assembly. If the Maven dependency isn't there then add it.